# The time my application displays does not change

Tags: android

I have a program which should display the current time. It displays the right time immediately after I install it to a phone. But after that, whenever I run the application, the time doesn't change at all.

Here's my code:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
date = day+"_"+month+"_"+year+"_";
Current_Time = date+ hour + "_" + minute + "_" + second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shekhar... I had the same misunderstanding. When you create an instance of calendar, it represents the date at which it was instantiated and that state does not change! So, to get the current "date" you need to create a new instance.

JAL

Comment: thanks JAL
could you please tell where should I create new instance of calendar in my program.

Comment: @Shekhar... Without understanding your needs, that is not possible, BUT if you call new Calendar in onCreate, the Date will be changed and represent the Date/Time when the Activity opens.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a method. Each call to create a new instance of the Calendar

Comment: could you please explain me pro-grammatically.